# Fill combobox with only numbers

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, range, fill

Hello I have this Excel Spreadsheet

[image]

I would like to fill my combobox `ComboBox1` only with the numbers in the given range.

So far I used this code to fill a combobox

```
With Worksheets("mySheet")
   ComboBox1.List = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
```

But this function fills my Combobox with all the values. Is there a way to make ComboBox recognize only numbers?

Edit:

With the `isNumeric()` worked nice but it inserts blank spaces like the picture below

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check like below.

```
For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     If IsNumeric(Range("A" & i).Value) And Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then ComboBox1.AddItem Range("A" & i).Value
Next i
```

Comment: One question. Do you know why It fills me the combobox with blank space on every number? I've could edit the question if you want to see the result.

Comment: @ChangeWorld Add a check as above and then test.